# imagejpeg and chmod

Tags: php, linux, cpanel, whm

I am facing below errors:

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/user1/public_html/userpics/00005/small/5120.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/user1/public_html/manage_picture.php on line 144

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /home/user1/public_html/manage_picture.php on line 145

---

Line 144 in code file is:
imagejpeg($idest, $dest, $quality);

Line 145 in code file is:

chmod($dest,0700);

I have cpanel and WHM interface, please guide how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a directory called `/home/user1/public_html/userpics/0005/small`?

Comment: No, it was not. I added directory and put permissions and it worked. But, can it be like create directory if do not exist?

Comment: @AslamKhan, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @Rob, you should put that in as an answer.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, I didn't want to steal your answer but if you insist :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the directory `/home/user1/public_html/userpics/00005/small` doesn't exist. You can use [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to make sure it does.